# Python decimal module not being consistent

Tags: python, decimal

In my python code, I am using the decimal module as I need a very high level of precision.

I have variables **a**, **b**, and **c**, where **c** = **a** / **b**.

I asked python to print out the following:

```
print "a: %.50f:" % (a),type(a)
print "b: %.50f:" % (b),type(b)
print "c: %.50f:" % (c),type(c)
```

which produced.

```
a: 0.00000006480000292147666645492911155490567409742653: <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
b: 43200001.94765111058950424194335937500000000000000000000000 <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
c: 0.00000000000000149999999999999991934287350973866750 <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

This is all fine, but then to check the value for **c**, I went into Python's interactive mode and copied and pasted those numbers directly:

```
a = decimal.Decimal('0.00000006480000292147666645492911155490567409742653')
b = decimal.Decimal('43200001.94765111058950424194335937500000000000000000000000')
```

The when I ask for **a** / **b**, I get:

```
Decimal('1.500000000000000013210016734E-15')
```

which is a slightly different result! I know that the floating point issues can make small imprecisions like this occur, but that's why I have been using the decimal module.

Can anyone tell me where the difference in these two answers is coming from please?

Comment: What is the context you are using(number of digits of precision?)?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by the context. I am making a simulation as part of my scientific research which requires a high level of precision. Apologies if that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: The `decimal` module allows you to modify the precision of the numbers using the `decimal.setcontext()` function. Are you using this to modify the default precision? If yes, what's the prevision that you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you print the values using string formatting (using `print "a: %.50f:" % (a),type(a)`), you implicitly convert them to floats!

You should rely on the decimal's print function, i.e. request a string from it:

```
print "a: %s:" % (a, type(a))
print "b: %s:" % (b, type(b))
print "c: %s:" % (c, type(c))
```

Comment: Fair enough. It is implicit in the sense that it might not be obvious to everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `format` method instead of `%` to format your `Decimal` values:

```
>>> c = Decimal('1.500000000000000013210016734E-15')
>>> print "c: %.50f" % c    # incorrect, conversion to float
c: 0.00000000000000149999999999999991934287350973866750
>>> print "c: {:.50f}".format(c)    # correct, no conversion
c: 0.00000000000000150000000000000001321001673400000000
```

As you can see, the error stems from the fact that formatting with `%` implicitly converts `c` to a float.